# I have no idea how to add new site to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

[the image when I hit "create property"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elWNZ.png)I want to add new site to google analytics.

When I was trying to create new property, I thought the first question would be "What would you like to track? Website of Mobile app", but it seems like different in my case as you can see the picture that I attached.

Does anyone have any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Universal Analytics Property just click on 'Show advanced options' button and create a new one. Otherwise, follow documentation for setup new GA4 Property: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9744165?hl=en